# Teradata releases - patch information deeply hidden?

Tags: security, version, teradata, updates, patch

For some reason, Teradata is really working on hiding such information. I'm looking for most recent patch release (security and maintenance updates) for Teradata DB for each core release above version 14 (14.00, 14.10, 15.00, 15.10, 16.00, 16.10 and 16.20). Missing parts are, e.g. 16.10.xx.yy. Having Teradata enterprise access didn't sort my issue at all - which is odd. Is some one able to tell me, where I could find such information?

Comment: When you have access to the patch server (Teradata Software Server) go to *Certified - Teradata Database*. There you can choose the release and OS...

Comment: Great. Sorted. Thank you.